# Rails. Has_many :through and form_for params for a checkbox field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

So I have this kind of association:

```
class FirstModel 
 has_many :merged_models
 has_many :second_models, :through => :merged_models
end

class SecondModel 
 has_many :merged_models
 has_many :first_models, :through => :merged_models
end

class MergedModel 
 belongs_to :first_model
 belongs_to :second_model
end
```

Now my problem is to understand this trick that helps `check_box_tag` helper to recognise elements in HTML from a passed collection in my form:

```
form_for(first_model) do |f|

  <% SecondModel.all.each do |s| -%>
    <div>
      <%= check_box_tag 'second_model_ids[]', s.id, first_model.second_models.include?(s), :name => 'first_model[second_model_ids][]'-%>
      <%= label_tag :second_model_ids, s.first_name -%>
    </div>
  <% end -%>
```

What I do not understand is this:

```
first_model.second_models.include?(s), :name => 'first_model[second_model_ids][]'
```

I believe that this:

```
first_model.second_models.include?(s)
```

checks if SecondModel's object id is already in FirstModel's `second_model_ids` array. In this case I would expect something like an if statement - if this id is there then do that, etc.

And this part makes me even more confused:

```
:name => 'first_model[second_model_ids][]'
```

Where that `:name` came from? Why `first_model[second_model_ids][]` have two square brackets - how they work in Rails syntax? To merge this newly checked id to the `second_model_ids` array?

I will appreciate all info. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So check_box_tag has this signature:

```
check_box_tag(name, value = "1", checked = false, options = {})
```

In your case:

```
check_box_tag 'second_model_ids[]', s.id, first_model.second_models.include?(s), :name => 'first_model[second_model_ids][]'
```

The first parameter (name) is 'second_model_ids[]', this will be used as the id= part of the tag.
The second parameter (value) of the checkbox is the id of s (current instance of SecondModel).
The third parameter (checked) is:

```
first_model.second_models.include?(s)
```

You are right about the meaning, and you don't need an 'if'.  The include?() returns a boolean (like most Ruby methods that end in a question mark).  You can try this in irb or rails console:

```
[1,2,3].include?(2)
# => true
```

The final option:

```
:name => 'first_model[second_model_ids][]'
```

passes in a hash of options which will be used as html. In this case a single hash value with the key :name (not to be confused with the first parameter above, which was used as the id='...' in the html tag), this will be used directly in the tag as

```
name='first_model[second_model_ids][]'
```

You were right about the syntax here also.  The brackets help Rails parse this into the correct nesting of the params hash with

```
first_model: {foo: 1, bar: 2, second_model: {some: stuff, other: stuff}}
```